# Why can I use ostream cout in a lambda although it wasn't captured?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

This lambda fails because I haven't *captured* the variable:

```
int main()
{
    int val = 5;
    auto lambda = []{ return val; };  // error: val wasn't captured.
    lambda();
}
```

But why does *ostream cout* work although it wasn't captured?

```
int main()
{
    auto lambda = []{ cout << endl; };  // works
}
```

Comment: `std::cout` is a global variable. It's visible to everybody.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because `std::cout` is defined in the following way (in the `<iostream>` header):

```
#include <ios>
#include <streambuf>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>

namespace std {
  extern istream cin;
  extern ostream cout;
  extern ostream cerr;
  extern ostream clog;
  extern wistream wcin;
  extern wostream wcout;
  extern wostream wcerr;
  extern wostream wclog;
}
```

while your `val` variable is defined locally (i.e. in the scope of the function/class).

Comment: This helped me understand